# simplest way to create email signup form that stays on top right of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

what is the simplest way to create a thin email signup bar at the top of the browser, that stays there as the user scrolls down and navigates to different pages? 
i'm using wordpress and I already have jquery loaded, but haven't programmed anything using jquery or wordpress yet. 
i've been mostly a user up to now and know html, css and some php and javascript. 
thanks
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a container div for the signup button and add it wherever you would like the button to appear (your page.php, single.php, index.php) or header.php to have it everywhere as another poster suggested. Here is a basic demo and some code that you can use:

**HTML**

```
<div class="signup">
    <a class="signupbtn" href="#" title="Sign up">Sign Up</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.signup {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:160px;
}

a.signupbtn {
    color: #6e6e6e;
    font: bold 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
    -moz-transition: border .218s;
    -o-transition: border-color .218s;
    transition: border-color .218s;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
a.signupbtn:hover {
    color: #333;
    border-color: #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
a.signupbtn:active {
    color: #000;
    border-color: #444;
}
```

And here's a basic demo of the button in use:

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/FAVK9/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `div` as in the example in HTML code on every page (I don't know how it looks in Wordpress, but there must be some header php file that is loaded on every page).

CSS:

```
div#signup{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:100px;
    min-height:30px;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="signup">
   Sign up
</div>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
```

**Edit:** I changed code a bit after the comment + added [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dnVdR/3/) (it interferes a bit with JSFiddle because their objects are also top-right aligned).

Comment: I missed 'right` in the title :) So yes, use `right:0` and change `width` to what you like.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you want something **to stick to a special place** even when browser scrolls, you should use **[fixed positioning](http://css-tricks.com/1191-absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)**.

I strongly suggest you read [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/) article (from A List Apart), to grasp what CSS Positioning means.